# How do i set the datepicker that allows user to choose between the current date and the current date + 15 days?

Tags: swift, datepicker

[This is my current code. I am not too sure how minimum and maximum date works. I have look some of the post regarding this matter but still could not get the code to work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fc7H.png)

Comment: Please post code as text and not as an image. Text is preferred because it can be copy/pasted into an editor and it is searchable.

Comment: ok noted. I will keep that in mind

Comment: No you shouldn't "keep that in mind". You should fix your current question now by editing it and making it more useful for the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

let currentDate = Date()
var components = DateComponents()
components.calendar = calendar

components.day = 15
let maxDate = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: currentDate)!

picker.minimumDate = currentDate
picker.maximumDate = maxDate
```